SvelteKit Routing with Vercel Page Load as White Page until Refresh
I've built several websites using SvelteKit and Vercel. I built a template that I clone to have a place to start from. All of the clones I've created work flawlessly until my most recent clone and I cannot figure it out. When you first visit the website it loads as expected. However, the first page you navigate to after the home page shows up as a white screen. If you refresh the page it loads as expected and then the site works fine. All other versions of this clone I've used to build sites do not experience this issue.
The only thing I've noticed is the following. When you click a link like the about page the url has an additional trailing / so it looks like this.
www.vibrationengineers.com/about/
Once I refresh the trailing / is gone and all other navigation excludes the /. All other sites using this clone do not have this trailing / on first click.
I verified this by looking at the following.
$: segment = $page.url.pathname
console.log(segment)

Two live site I have are listed below. I'm looking at the console on the live sites and on localhost and they don't give me any error.
Working Site
www.consultjct.com
Site With Error
www.vibrationengineers.com
If any one has any thoughts I'd appreciate it. It seems like a routing issue but it could be something else. Happy to share code but just not sure what to share based on the oddity of this bug.

I solved this by recloning the master template. It appears that the initial clone was corrupt. Once recloned I transferred all code and created a new project in Vercel. All works flawlessly now.
